# Plot multiple x for one y in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is a part of the data set I have.

```
 type     lipids    variable     value
0      WT  PC [32:1]        13C   0.237396
27    SHC  PC [32:1]        13C   0.024194
52     WT  PC [32:1]        13C   0.218098
79    SHC  PC [32:1]        13C   0.033292
104    WT  PC [32:1]        13C   0.205793
131   SHC  PC [32:1]        13C   0.046538
156    WT  PC [32:1]        20C   0.197620
183   SHC  PC [32:1]        20C   0.046370
208    WT  PC [32:1]        20C   0.190123
235   SHC  PC [32:1]        20C   0.037380
260    WT  PC [32:1]        20C   0.192144
287   SHC  PC [32:1]        20C   0.034143
```

I would like to make a scatter plot in Python, where on x axes I would have variable and on y - value, colored by type. It is a bit tricky as I have 3 values for each variable. I would be happy to get any hint how to do that. I was playing with matplotlib however without success.

Comment: Do you have any code that doesn't work as expected that you could post?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Showing your code would greatly clarify your intent here.  It will also show us where particularly you are falling short.  Since you were asked for code 2 hours ago and not yet updated your question or replied, I'm going to go ahead and vote to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking".  Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center for more information.